# Get Browser to send both If-None-Match and If-Modified-Since

Tags: php, http, if-modified-since

My Browser isn't sending back an If-Modified-Since Header for PHP generated Content

on the first request my script sends:

```
(Status-Line) HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date Thu, 21 Jan 2010 08:55:25 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.2.9-1
X-Powered-By PHP/5.2.9-1
Pragma no-cache
x-ua-compatible IE=8;FF=3;OtherUA=4
Last-Modfied Sat, 02 Jan 2010 02:02:20 GMT
Content-Length 28453
Etag b98e0795b509be20146f58e06fbb624f
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=90
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Type image/png
```

it on the second request it sends:

```
(Request-Line) GET /kincumberunitingchurch/banner_image.php?id=1 HTTP/1.1
Host localhost
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.17) Gecko/2009122116 Firefox/3.0.17
Accept image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive 300
Connection keep-alive
Referer http://localhost/kincumberunitingchurch/index.php?sid=tgl9jq3f71nau3cj9vps6pna03
Cookie sid=tgl9jq3f71nau3cj9vps6pna03; PHPSESSID=m0jvven6d7l65pl6odm9ecfnt4
If-None-Match b98e0795b509be20146f58e06fbb624f
Cache-Control max-age=0
```

for other files the sever sends first:

```
(Status-Line) HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date Thu, 21 Jan 2010 08:55:25 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.2.9-1
Last-Modified Wed, 30 Dec 2009 02:40:58 GMT
Etag "1000000013d35-40d9-47be9117f6280"
Accept-Ranges bytes
Content-Length 16601
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=84
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Type image/png
```

and my browser send the following on the next request:

```
(Request-Line) GET /kincumberunitingchurch/img/cbuttons.png HTTP/1.1
Host localhost
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.17) Gecko/2009122116 Firefox/3.0.17
Accept image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive 300
Connection keep-alive
Referer http://localhost/kincumberunitingchurch/mystyle.css
Cookie sid=tgl9jq3f71nau3cj9vps6pna03; PHPSESSID=m0jvven6d7l65pl6odm9ecfnt4
If-Modified-Since Wed, 30 Dec 2009 02:40:58 GMT
If-None-Match "1000000013d35-40d9-47be9117f6280"
Cache-Control max-age=0
```

why would it send the If-Modified-Since header

Answer (score 0):

Your first sended header reads "Last-Modfied", which is a typo (the first 'i' in Modified is missing).

Comment: ...it would be cool, if the browser would send back an `If-Modfied-Since` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

can you look if the Last-Modfied inside the first example isn't a typo at the server side